# Twilio Salesforce related

Tags: templates, salesforce, twilio, sms

Created Text Templates in the Content Editor in the Twilio Account but I don't see how can I use those SMS Templates in Salesforce.

I don't see how can I try using SMS templates in Salesforce. The template I create in the Twilio account has the name given and a 34 character Id.